# Solutions to solve the encoding issue in this code

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8

Please see the code below

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            ¿Hola cómo está?
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this code, i want to print the characters properly as given in the file. 1 solution is to save the file in UTF-8 format. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Use HTML symbols such as &pound; for example. http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: @craig1231: I would post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saving the file as UTF-8 is insufficient. You should also signal the HTTP client (browser) that it's a UTF-8 document.
This can be done in two ways:

1. By forcing the server to send appropriate headers - this usually means you must have the ability to at least somewhat alter the server's configuration.
2. Insert `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />` into `<head>` element.

To your original question, the encoding of the PHP file can be different - you'll just have to re-encode the string from the local encoding to UTF-8 before you send it.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML symbols such as £ for example.

http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm